# how to replace image by alternative div

Tags: javascript, html

I have an ebook website and I would like to replace the image by a `div` when the image does not display.
the `div` will contain a *background image* with the title of the book.

[image: Book]

This is the code I used to obtain this

```
  <a href="#popup1">
     <img src="uploadimages/<?=$image['image']?>" alt="<?=$image['titre']?> " />

     <div class="altimage">
     <div class="alttitle"><?=$image['titre']?></div>

        <img src="uploadimages/couvalt.png"/>            
     </div>
  </a>
```

But I don't want to show the two in same time but the second if the first doest not display.
I have found this code on the forum

```
<img src="https://imageurl.com" alt="Image not found" onerror="this.src='https://alternativeimageurl.com'" />
```

but it only allow me to put an alternative image but not an alternative image with a text.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `onerror` there is an event handler. This allows you to run any code.

```js
function not_found(elem) {
  elem.src = 'https://picsum.photos/200';
  var caption = elem.closest('.wrapper').querySelector('.caption')
  caption.classList.add("not-found");
  caption.innerText = elem.getAttribute("alt");
  caption.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <img src="https://imageurl.com" alt="Image not found" onerror="not_found(this)" />
  <div class="caption"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: i tried it i works very well thank you